# Python: How to make (3d) plots of functions without needing linspace/meshgrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, sympy

#### Question:

[In WolframAlpha, I can get a plot for "z = x^2 - y^2"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20z%20%3D%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2) directly from that string. How would one make plots like the above from a string in python?

#### A few things I already know about:

- You can do [linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) or [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), compute the function at each point, and then pass those values to either [matplotlib](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html) or [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/). Plotly makes beautiful plots in this case, and this is what I'm using right now, but it's definitely still a hassle.
- [It's possible to do plotting in Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html), but that library is a little heavy-handed in its own way, and the documentation is a little sparse.

#### What would make a great answer:

- A library I haven't heard of or been able to find which provides easy, elegant plotting of functions without needing to do the linspace myself.
- A thorough explanation of why the available tools I listed above are the best you can do, and perhaps some tutorials you like for getting a better grasp of these techniques.

#### Updates:

- This seems relevant: https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting

Comment: [Ask *how*, not *what*.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for pointing me towards that meta thread. I wasn't aware. How is the question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sympy` has a plotting module, pretty much just the example code

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
x, y = symbols('x y')

plot3d((x**2 - y**2))
```

[image]